# How to tell automake to find my version of aclocal when recompiling hunspell?

Tags: automake, m4, hunspell

I am currently recompiling hunspell from the git source downloaded from fedora as follows:

```
git://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/hunspell.git
```

As mentioned by the steps in HACKING, I installed all prerequisite and execute the build commands:

```
autoconf && ./configure && make
```

And I received this error message:

```
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && aclocal-1.13 -I m4
/bin/bash: aclocal-1.13：命令找不到 (command not found)
Makefile:463: recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

My computer has automake 1.14 installed.

```
tom@bktkowks04:~/Development/hunspell$ aclocal --version
aclocal (GNU automake) 1.14.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>
       and Alexandre Duret-Lutz <adl@gnu.org>.

tom@bktkowks04:~/Development/hunspell$ which aclocal
/usr/bin/aclocal
tom@bktkowks04:~/Development/hunspell$
```

Which the offending statement happends when the system is "make"ing.  Is there anyway for me to tell make to locate my aclocal?  I tried to trace the steps when making.  Shall I post the steps listed?

Thanks all.

Comment: Try `autoreconf -fvi` instead of `autoconf`?

Comment: Working, as  I still need to install autopoint and libtool to run autoreconfig.  Will tell you results once  I have got it.